# bitbucket bddc1783b136 [bddc1783b136] errors

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I upload my project files by smartgit/hg to bitbucket. But when I clone the repository in another computer. I got many empty folders that expected to contain many .java files.

So I open bitbucket.org in my browser, and find the repository--click "source". It shows "**back → bddc1783b136 [bddc1783b136]**"

the pic is on : http://img3.picbed.org/uploads/2014/04/abc.jpg

"back" is one of the folders that uploaded and expected to be contains many .java files.

I wonder if someone tell me what happens. I tried to google the error message but got nothing.

I did see success message of finishing pull in smartgit/hg.

PS: The project folder is really big--567 MB. It works well when I doing with a small project.

*I am not a native English speaker, So if I didn't describe the problem well, please forgive me. :)*

**UPDATE:**

Now I use hg instead of git and use TortoiseHg instead of smartgit/hg.
This fixes the problem.